# Where can I find modern python code that is used in real applications?

Tags: python-3.x

In the internet, I see basic python code all over and I wanted to know where I can study (such as specific websites) code that is being used in real life applications. It's like asking for a snippet of source code from a real application.

Comment: most everything in [PyPI - the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), [Python on Mercurial](https://hg.python.org/) and countless repositories hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/trending/python), [BitButcket](https://bitbucket.org/) and many other code hosting sites

Comment: A sea of open source applications on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

As an example check out [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) an opensource Python web framework used in real world production.

[This](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy) is the git repository.

Wikipedia has a [List of Python software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software)